# How to detect keypress event in browser console?

Tags: javascript

Can we detect keypress events in browser console? If so, how?

```
window.addEventListener( 'keyup', function (e) {
  if ( e.keyCode == 13 ) {
    // Should log the message, if user presses 'enter' key, in browser console?
    console.log('Hello World');
  }
});
```

P.S Can we add an eventListener to browser's console?

Comment: No, that’s not possible.

Comment: At this time thats a great NO WAY. You are able to interact with the DOM. The console is not part if the DOM.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? There might be other ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: Post the problem that you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can not detect a keypress event in the browser console. Javascript can manipulate the DOM, which the browser console is not part of and as such, it can not be manipulated with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You would like so:

```
const handleKeyUp = (e: KeyboardEvent): void => {
  console.log(
    '\n:::::::::::::::::::::handleKeyUp:::::::::::::::::::::::',
    '\n:: e.code ::',
    e.code,
    '\n:: e.key ::',
    e.key,
    '\n:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::'
  );

  if (e.code === 'Escape') {
    setMyThing(true);
  }
};

document.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp);
```

Not sure which key code to use?
https://keycode.info/

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ClI1/owrb9vhz/4/

Comment: This won't detect a key pressed __in__ the browser console.

Comment: @Danziger link to example showing key press in console added

Comment: The OP's asking how to detect when the user presses a key inside the browser console itself, which is outside the document, it's not part of the DOM. Your code is listening for `keyup` in the document (not the console itself) and logging some information to the console.